# Can men also become only bald on their legs?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology

Often hair loss that primarily affects the top and front of the scalp will happen to men (and female) during aging. Male pattern hair loss is believed to be due to a combination of genetics and the male hormone dihydrotestosterone.

Men with androgenic alopecia typically have higher 5-alpha-reductase, lower total testosterone, higher unbound/free testosterone, and higher free androgens, including DHT.

The question is whether this kind of balding is only present in the hair of the scalp or can this proces also happen on the legs (or other parts of the body)?

Answer (score 1):

Hair loss is known as [**alopecia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alopecia_areata), and is often associated with hair loss on the head. This type of hair loss is most noticeable, but hair loss can occur in nearly any part of the body, including the legs (source: [Healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health/hair-loss-and-testosterone)). As an anecdote - my father in law (65+) has lost all his hair on his legs. This hair loss is referred to as [anterolateral leg alopecia](https://www.healthline.com/health/hair-loss-on-legs#diagnosis)

About 35 percent of older men have this condition. The exact causes of anterolateral leg alopecia are unknown, but there may be a genetic component.

Age related hair loss in men is referred to as male pattern baldness, or **[androgenic alopecia](https://www.healthline.com/health/hair-loss-and-testosterone)**. This type is related to hormones and certain genes.

Comment: For those who are interested, [here](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-018-04807-3) is the current best genomic predictor of male-pattern baldness. Currently, about 15-20% of the variance in liability can be predicted directly from DNA (will increase when better data comes).